# forEach only uses first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got some sort of HTML Code as a List with links in each list item. I want to get those with JavaScript and only log them first for later usage. It's a List of jobs which have a title, link and location.

The code looks kind of like this:

```js
var jobs = document.getElementsByClassName("offerlist-item");

var jobList = [].slice.call(jobs);
var jobAnchor;
var jobName;
var jobUrl;
var jobLocation;

jobList.forEach(function(job) {
  jobAnchor = $('h3.styleh3').html();
  jobUrl = $(jobAnchor).attr('href');
   jobName = $(jobAnchor).text();
  
  jobLocation = $("li.noBorder").text();
 
  console.log(this.jobUrl);
  console.log(jobName);
  console.log(jobLocation);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   
  <li class="offerlist-item">
        <h3 class="styleh3">
            <a href="someUrl1">
                SomeTitle1
            </a>
        </h3>
    <ul>
      <li><li class="noBorder">someLocation1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="offerlist-item">
        <h3 class="styleh3">
            <a href="someUrl2">
                SomeTitle2
            </a>
        </h3>
    <ul>
      <li><li class="noBorder">someLocation2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="offerlist-item">
        <h3 class="styleh3">
            <a href="someUrl3">
                SomeTitle3
            </a>
        </h3>
    <ul>
      <li><li class="noBorder">someLocation3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

My problem is that only the first item is used in the forEach loop. Why is that so?

Comment: Pass context to jquery `jobAnchor = $('h3.styleh3',job).html();`

Comment: `$('h3.styleh3')` will always be the same thing. Use `$('h3.styleh3', job)` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! The same problem was for jobLocation. It's fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your HTML is invalid. You've got an open `li` with no closing tag.

Secondly, the issue is because you're looking up *every* `h3.styleh3` within each iteration of the loop. You should instead look at the ones *inside* the current `job`. You can do that using `find()`, like this:

```js
var jobs = document.getElementsByClassName("offerlist-item");

var jobList = [].slice.call(jobs);
var jobAnchor;
var jobName;
var jobUrl;
var jobLocation;

jobList.forEach(function(job) {
  jobAnchor = $(job).find('h3.styleh3').html();
  jobUrl = $(jobAnchor).attr('href');
  jobName = $(jobAnchor).text();

  jobLocation = $(job).find("li.noBorder").text();

  console.log(this.jobUrl);
  console.log(jobName);
  console.log(jobLocation);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="offerlist-item">
    <h3 class="styleh3">
      <a href="someUrl1">SomeTitle1</a>
    </h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="noBorder">someLocation1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="offerlist-item">
    <h3 class="styleh3">
      <a href="someUrl2">SomeTitle2</a>
    </h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="noBorder">someLocation2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="offerlist-item">
    <h3 class="styleh3">
      <a href="someUrl3">SomeTitle3</a>
    </h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="noBorder">someLocation3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

However it's worth noting that you're using an odd mix of native JS methods and jQuery. It's best to use either one or the other. Here's a pure jQuery implementation:

```js
$('.offerlist-item').each(function() {
  var $job = $(this);
  var $jobAnchor = $job.find('h3.styleh3 a');
  var jobUrl = $jobAnchor.attr('href');
  var jobName = $jobAnchor.text();
  var jobLocation = $job.find("li.noBorder").text();

  console.log(jobUrl);
  console.log(jobName);
  console.log(jobLocation);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="offerlist-item">
    <h3 class="styleh3">
      <a href="someUrl1">SomeTitle1</a>
    </h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="noBorder">someLocation1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="offerlist-item">
    <h3 class="styleh3">
      <a href="someUrl2">SomeTitle2</a>
    </h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="noBorder">someLocation2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="offerlist-item">
    <h3 class="styleh3">
      <a href="someUrl3">SomeTitle3</a>
    </h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="noBorder">someLocation3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There where a few problems:

1. Not necessarily a problem, but I replaces `document.getElementsByClassName("offerlist-item")` with the simple jQuery selector `$('.offerlist-item')`, which also reners `[].slice.call(jobs)` unnecessary
2. You always used the selector `$('h3.styleh3')` no matter what the currently looped job was. You can change that now, by using `$a.find(sel)`. This will find all elements with the given selector "sel" that are children of "a".

```js
var jobList = $('.offerlist-item');
var jobAnchor;
var jobName;
var jobUrl;
var jobLocation;

jobList.each(function() {
  jobAnchor = $(this).find('h3.styleh3').html();
  jobUrl = $(jobAnchor).attr('href');
   jobName = $(jobAnchor).text();
  
  jobLocation = $("li.noBorder").text();
 
  console.log(this.jobUrl);
  console.log(jobName);
  console.log(jobLocation);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   
  <li class="offerlist-item">
        <h3 class="styleh3">
            <a href="someUrl1">
                SomeTitle1
            </a>
        </h3>
    <ul>
      <li><li class="noBorder">someLocation1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="offerlist-item">
        <h3 class="styleh3">
            <a href="someUrl2">
                SomeTitle2
            </a>
        </h3>
    <ul>
      <li><li class="noBorder">someLocation2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="offerlist-item">
        <h3 class="styleh3">
            <a href="someUrl3">
                SomeTitle3
            </a>
        </h3>
    <ul>
      <li><li class="noBorder">someLocation3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```